# Proving uniform convergence of series

Tags: sequences-and-series

[image: Series]

I've been trying to prove uniform convergence of the given series. I've figured that the only way to do it is to use Cauchy's condition. I'm getting this

[image]

At this point, it's impossible to create n-E dependency, with x hanging around. Am I doing something wrong, or this series isn't uniformly convergent? I would really appreciate your help,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**hint**

By MVT,

$$|\arctan(X)-\arctan(0)|=\frac {|X|}{1+c^2} $$

$$\leq|X|$$

thus for $n>0$,

$$|u_n (x)|\leq \frac {2|x|}{n^2+x^2}\leq \frac{2|x|}{n^2} .$$

your series of functions is normally and uniformly convergent in each compact $[A,B] $ of $\mathbb R $.

Comment: Could you please explain how you got the last expression?

Comment: @ArtieHerasymov Look now, i edited.